# How do I index my MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if anyone could show me how to INDEX my MySQL query I have made.  It takes forever to load from a database that only has 120 rows.

My query is :

```
 $sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email, phone, username, password, status, 
memberview, statuschangedate FROM csvdata ORDER BY lastname ";

$sth= $DBH->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
code
}
```

Thank you for your time!

EDITED--------------------------

Here is what is actually going on -

```
   $sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email, phone, username, password, status, memberview, statuschangedate FROM csvdata ORDER BY lastname ";
   $sth= $DBH->prepare($sql);
   $sth->execute();
   $i = 0;
                                echo "<table class='alltable'> 
                                      <tr class='firsttr' style='background:gray;'>
                                      <td>First Name </td>
                                      <td>Last Name </td>
                                      <td>Email </td>
                                      <td>Phone </td>
                                      <td>Username </td>
                                      <td>Password </td>
                                      <td>Status </td>
                                      <td>Memberview</td>
                                      <td>Status Change Date</td>
                                      <td>#</td>
                                      </tr>

                                        ";
                                        $j = 0;
                                while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                    $csvfirst = $row;
                                    $csvfirstname = $csvfirst['firstname'];
                                    $csvlastname = $csvfirst['lastname'];
                                    $csvemail = $csvfirst['email'];
                                    $csvphone = $csvfirst['phone'];
                                    $csvusername = $csvfirst['username'];
                                    $csvpassword= $csvfirst['password'];
                                    $csvstatus = $csvfirst['status'];
                                    $csvmemberview = $csvfirst['memberview'];
                                    $csvstatuschange = $csvfirst['statuschangedate'];

                                        $memberfirstnamearray[$j]  = $csvfirstname;
                                    $memberlastnamearray[$j]  = $csvlastname;
                                    $memberemailarray[$j]  = $csvemail;
                                    $memberphonearray[$j]  = $csvphone;
                                    $j++;
                                $i++;

                                    echo "
                                            <tr> 
                                        <td>
                                        $csvfirstname
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        $csvlastname
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        $csvemail
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        $csvphone
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        $csvusername
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        $csvpassword
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        $csvstatus
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        $csvmemberview
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        $csvstatuschange
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        $i
                                        </td>

                                      </tr>
                                    ";

                                }
                                $_SESSION['firstnameexport'] = $memberfirstnamearray;
                                $_SESSION['lastnameexport'] = $memberlastnamearray;
                                $_SESSION['emailexport'] = $memberemailarray;
                                $_SESSION['phoneexport'] = $memberphonearray;
                                $_SESSION['num'] = $j;
                                echo "
                                      </table>";

                }
```

so with about 120 employees it grabs from database it takes about almost 20 secounds to load.  I have this table contained in a `div` that than has a button and once you clock it, jquery changes `visibility: none` to visible and does a slide down.

Let me know if you need anything else!

EDITED----------------------

from using desc csvdata - It is the employees that is taking forever.

```
    'id', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', NULL, 'auto_increment'
'firstname', 'varchar(105)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'lastname', 'varchar(105)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'email', 'varchar(105)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'phone', 'varchar(105)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'username', 'varchar(105)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'password', 'varchar(105)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'status', 'varchar(105)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'memberview', 'varchar(105)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'statuschangedate', 'varchar(105)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'notes', 'varchar(1000)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
'customernotes', 'varchar(1000)', 'YES', '', NULL, ''
```

Comment: It is very unlikely to take forever for 120 rows judging from the column names you posted. Post your actual schema definition and some example data.

Comment: Something else is wrong most likely.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html if it is an index issue you'll want to put an index on lastname as you order by it

Comment: indexes are only of use if you're doing joins or filtering with `where`. it MAY be of use to index the lastname field to help with the ordering, but with 120 rows, there's something else screwy. But for small data sets, mysql can sometimes choose to ignore indexes and just do full table scans anyways, to save on the index load overhead.

Comment: I just updated code @lanzz this is going to have thousands of rows.

Comment: As others have said, that's extremely weird if it's taking that long for 120 rows.  MySQL should be able to handle a million rows in a relatively quick way.  Is this running off a 386? =).  Btw, to post your schema, in mysql call the command: "desc members" and post the results of that.  Also run "show index from members" so we can see the indexes currently on the table.

Comment: @adam how do I call that command, just in my query? `$sql = "desc members";`

Comment: @adam no this is through Win Host so not to sure.

Comment: Yeah - do you have a MySQL client and the ability to connect to the server?  You could call it from PHP, I suppose, but you would need to throw together a little script and have the results dumped out to the page.

Comment: @adam just posted what I got from your above code.

Comment: Can you show the results of "show index from csvdata", too?  I'm curious if you have any indexes on there currently.  I don't see anything wrong with your schema.  Your notes fields are pretty large, but that shouldn't cause any significant delays on 120 rows, and you're not even querying those fields.

Comment: I suspect the issue is not with the query itself.  Try timing the query from your PHP: put `$t = microtime(TRUE);` before the call to execute the query; then `$t = microtime(TRUE) - $t;` right after it - and output the value of `$t`.  This will tell you the actual time the query took, as opposed to how long the entire script took to execute.

Comment: @aleksG it printed out right away 0.0044610500335693 was the output......... I have a button where you click to view now and It slides everything down so you can view it....do you think its because of that?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys you know what the issue was?

It was the JQuery slidedown() that was delaying it so I just switched it to change the css to display: table and worked perfect!

Code -

```
<script>
$(".viewall").click(function () {

    //dropdown.bind('change', function(){   
    //$(".alltable").slideDown(0,function(){
    //});
    $(".alltable").css("display", "table");
    $(".alltable tr").css("display", "table-row");
    $(".alltable td").css("display", "table-cell");
    //$(".alltable tr").slideDown(0,function(){
    //});
    //$(".alltable td").slideDown(0,function(){
    //});
});
$(".closeall").click(function () {

    //dropdown.bind('change', function(){   
    /*$(".alltable").slideUp(200,function(){
    });*/
    $(".alltable").css("display", "none");
    $(".alltable tr").css("display", "none");
    $(".alltable td").css("display", "none");
    /*$(".alltable tr").slideUp(200,function(){
    });
    $(".alltable td").slideUp(200,function(){
    });*/
});

</script>
```